# How to set maximum fullscreen in vmware?

Tags: fullscreen, vmware-workstation

I'm using VMware workstation 8 on windows 7 and having some Linux hosts such as Centos, Backtrack and ... on it.
The problem is the screen of the virtual machines is not fixed with my screen.
here is the picture from my screen: https://s15.postimg.cc/7carokj4r/Capture.png

Comment: For me, in my VMWare workstation this works for me, under View >> Fix Guest Now.

Answer (score 45):

Change the resolution of your operating system running in VMware and hope it will stretch the screen when chosen the correct values

Comment: Great... it worked for me as well.

Comment: its good, working for me on VMware station with Kali 2

Answer (score 8):

Go to view and press "Switch to scale mode" which will adjust the virtual screen when you adjust the application.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me as if you actually mean "linux guests" and not "linux hosts".

But in any case, I suspect you did not install the VMWare Tools: doubleclick on that icon on the Desktop that can be seen on your screenshot. It will install some drivers that communicate with VMWare that, among other things, allow to adjust the screen resolution dynamically.

When the installation process is finished, you'll most likely have to reboot the VM.

Comment: the problem solved in Centos by changing the resulation.and not solved in backtrack. I know about vmware tools.  but when I click it says unavailable. here is the another problem

Comment: [This link](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_newguest_tools_linux.html#wp1118025) should help with installing the Tools.

Answer (score 0):

From you main machine, start -> search -> "remote desktop connection"  -> click on "remote desktop connection"  -> Click "Options" Beside to "Connect Button" -> Display Tab - > Then increase Display Configuriton Size. If this will not work, try the same thing by closing remote desktop. But this will give you solution.